# Add query string using pushstate

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string, browser-history, pushstate

I am doing something like below

```
if(history.pushState)
{
    var stateObject = { dummy: true };
    var url = window.location.protocol
        + "//"
        + window.location.host
        + window.location.pathname
        + '?myNewUrlQuery=1';
    history.pushState(stateObject, jQuery(document).find('title').text(), + url);
}
```

I am getting pathname correct, but getting query string as Nan. For example I am getting result like

```
http://example.com/mypage/Nan
```

Instead of

```
http://example.com/page/?myNewUrlQuery=1
```

Please tell me is it possible to add query string in URL using pushstate method. If yes, any working example will be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
+ url
```

You have a Unary plus operator before the `url` variable that converts it to a number. Since it isn't a string containing a number you get *Not A Number* instead. Remove the `+`.

Comment: OMG ! I can't imagine that I made such a silly mistake. Anyways thanks a lot Quentin for pointing it out.